# How to obtain the maximum datetime of each item2 & item3 combination?

Tags: c#, linq

I have data from external system in a tuple like this, have lots of item2 and item 3 combinations with different datetime.

```
var data = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<DateTime, string, string>(new DateTime(2021, 04, 01, 5, 10, 20), "A1", "X1"),
    new Tuple<DateTime, string, string>(new DateTime(2021, 04, 01, 6, 10, 22), "A1", "X1"),
    new Tuple<DateTime, string, string>(new DateTime(2021, 04, 02, 7, 11, 21), "A2", "X2")
};
```

Now I need to fetch MAX datetime against each unique item2 & item3 combinations and return result should be this,

```
var result = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<DateTime, string, string>(new DateTime(2021, 04, 01, 6, 10, 22), "A1", "X1"),
    new Tuple<DateTime, string, string>(new DateTime(2021, 04, 02, 7, 11, 21), "A2", "X2")
};
```

I am able to fetch MAX datetime for each item2 and item3 combinations where I am passing these values as hard code,

```
 var maxTimestamp = data.Where(t => t.Item2 == "A1" && t.Item3 == "X1").Max(t => t.Item1);
```

but I need to iterate each item2 and item3 combinations, how to do this?

Comment: FYI, [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) provides more convenient syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`:

```
var maxTimestamps = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item2, x.Item3}).
                         Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Item1).First());
```

You will get groups with the same `Item2` and `Item3`. Sort these groups by their date and pick the first date of each group.